# How to breed a Coolfire dragon in dragon city?

Tags: dragon-city

So, this Coolfire dragon in dragon city is quite hard to breed if you do not have a double flame dragon (which I don't have). And now it is required to participate in a battle in the frozen wind cup! Could somebody tell how to breed it?

Comment: I found a [link](https://dragoncityguide.net/how-to-breed-juggernaut/) of parents (?) to get the Juggernaut Dragon, a lot of the combinations do not require Double Flame. Note, I do not play this game :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant Coolfire dragon:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this [link](https://dragoncityguide.net/how-to-breed-Cool+Fire/?basic=0) you can find some breeding options, most of which do not include the double flame dragon.

Some of the easier ones are:
Blizzard and Icecube which have a 6.9% chance of getting cool fire.[image: Blizzard and Icecube]

Next are Medieval and Alpine which have a 12.5% chance of getting cool fire.

[image: Medieval and Alpine]

You could also try Butterfly and Dandelion which have a 5.67% chance of getting cool fire.

[image: Butterfly and Dandelion]

You can get Butterfly with the login bonuses along with Double Flame which can basically solve your problem of not having one.

Comment: Please edit your answer to summarize the information contained there. That way, if that page ever goes down, your answer is still valid, and it also saves people a click.

Comment: It shows many combinations, I can't possibly put them all in. If I knew which dragons he/she had, I could put the relevant combinations.

Comment: Then I'm afraid this isn't a very good answer, and is subject to deletion.  We would define this as a link only answer, which suffers from the problems I mentioned, and are not the type of answers we would like.

Comment: Let's hope Oliver replies then...

Comment: I don't think you understand; your answer needs to stand even without any reply from the asker.  If you can't answer without more information from the asker, then you should be commenting with the extra information you need, not answering.  What's likely going to happen is you'll get no reply, and this answer will be deleted in short order.

Comment: Added the easiest ones to obtain, thanks for the feedback.